# Calculating age from datetimepicker and instantly showing that age in textbox

Tags: c#

i want to calculate age from datetimepicker.
As soon as user selects date from datetimepicker age is calculated and then is shown automatically in age textbox instantly.
this is what i have done in console application

```
 int age = 0;
 DateTime currentDate = DateTime.Parse( DateTime.Now.Date.ToShortDateString());           
 Console.WriteLine(currentDate);
 Console.WriteLine("Please enter your birthdate");
 DateTime birthdate = DateTime.Parse( Console.ReadLine());
 age = currentDate.Year - birthdate.Year;
 if (currentDate.Month <birthdate.Month)
  {
       age--;
  }
 else if ((currentDate.Month >= birthdate.Month) 
            && (currentDate.Day < birthdate.Day))
 {
       age--;
 }

 Console.WriteLine(age);
```

I can do same logic of calculating age in winform application.But i do not have any idea after that,how to show that age in age textbox automatically instantly after user have selected age from datetimepicker.

Comment: You could make your `currentDate` more efficient by saving the date directly `DateTime currentDate = DateTime.Now.Date;`. You *don't* need to convert to `String` and then parse back to `DateTime`.

Comment: I tend to find it easier to just write int age = `(int)(DateTime.Now.Subtract(birthday).TotalDays / 365.25)`, it's less code and easier to read IMO

Comment: Thank You guys.I really appreciate your help. I am still learning C#.so i might and will ask lot of questions,so plz help me like this,in the future as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, that's rather simple. Just add eventhandler listening to datepicker's `OnValueChanged` event. Refer [msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/system.windows.forms.datetimepicker.aspx) page for help.
 And just set textbox's value like this `myTextBox.Text = new calculated value`.

Answer (score 3):

I know its too late to answer but still , Simply use this on ValueChanged event of dateTimePicker,Hope it helps to someone

```
private void dateTimePicker1_ValueChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            int Age = DateTime.Today.Year - dateTimePicker1.Value.Year; // CurrentYear - BirthDate

             txtAge.Text = Age.ToString();
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Just add the ValueChanged event to your DateTimePicker.

[MSDN ValueChanged Event](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datetimepicker.valuechanged.aspx)

This event is called after the form has changed its value.
Your code will look like this:

```
dateTimePicker.ValueChanged += new EventHandler(dateTimePicker_ValueChanged);

void dateTimePicker_ValueChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    DateTime birthdate = dateTimePicker.Value;
    //Recalculate the birthdate and set Textbox
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you have a bug here:

```
else if ((currentDate.Month >= birthdate.Month) 
            && (currentDate.Day < birthdate.Day))
 {
       age--;
 }
```

it should be `(currentDate.Month == birthdate.Month)`